# multiple counts on an object in a doctrine 2 query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, count, query-builder

I am trying to do **multiple counts** on an entity in a doctrine 2 query.

I am able to get the count correctly when I do a single count but run into problems when I do **multiple counts** in the same query.

Also, my query returns the entity; but I don't want the entity. I just want the counts.

This is my query;

```
public function getMessagesCount()
{ 
    $qb = $this->queryBuilder();

    $qb->select(array('u','count(fa)as favouritesAdded','count(se)as sentMessages' ))
        ->from('BaseModel\Entity\User','u')
        ->leftJoin('u.theFavouriteAdded', 'fa')
        ->leftJoin('u.sentMessagesObject', 'se')     
        ->where('u.id = :identifier')
        ->setParameter('identifier',(int)$this->getUserId());

    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    return   $data = $query->getArrayResult();        
}
```

This query returns the same numbers for both counts (i.e both incorrectly returned a count of 20 each)

However, when I did just a single count for each; they query returned the correct account each time. i.e;

```
public function getMessagesCounts()
{ 
    $qb = $this->queryBuilder();

    $qb->select(array('u','count(fa)as favouritesAdded' ))
        ->from('BaseModel\Entity\User','u')
        ->leftJoin('u.theFavouriteAdded', 'fa')
     //   ->leftJoin('u.sentMessagesObject', 'se')     
        ->where('u.id = :identifier')         
        ->setParameter('identifier',(int)$this->getUserId());

    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    return   $data = $query->getArrayResult();             
}
```

I tried adding a group by to the query; but it still returned the incorrect numbers.i.e

**`->groupBy("u.favouritesAdded","u.sentMessages")`**

What is the correct way to do a multiple count on a query?

Answer (score 0):

### For single count:

(returns count without returning entities)

```
public function getMessagesCounts()
{ 
    $qb = $this->queryBuilder();
    $qb->select('count(se)')
        ->from('BaseModel\Entity\User','u')
        ->leftJoin('u.sentMessagesObject', 'se')     
        ->where('u.id = :identifier')         
        ->setParameter('identifier', (int) $this->getUserId());

    return  $qb->$query->getResult(); 
}
```

### For two in one count:

```
public function getMessagesCounts()
{ 
    $qb = $this->queryBuilder();
    $qb->select('count(fa), count(se)')
        ->from('BaseModel\Entity\User','u')
        ->leftJoin('u.theFavouriteAdded', 'fa')
        ->leftJoin('u.sentMessagesObject', 'se')     
        ->where('u.id = :identifier')         
        ->setParameter('identifier', (int) $this->getUserId());

    return  $qb->$query->getResult(); 
}
```

Comment: @PaulKendal Did you try my solution? Does it do what you want?